# Android custom LinearLayout onTouchListener for child views not working

Tags: android, android-custom-view, ontouchlistener

I'm trying to intercept `onTouch` event for a child view within my custom `LinearLayout`, but the attached listener is not getting called.

```
@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();

    mChild1 = getChildAt(0);
    mChild2 = getChildAt(1);

    mChild2.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.log("On touuuuuuuuuuuuuch");
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

The Logcat's console is empty, the `onTouch` event isn't called.

My second cell from the LinearLayout is a `ViewPager`, maybe the touch event is delivered there? I have also tried with `mChild1` which is a simple TextView, and the `onTouch` event listener is called.

Comment: It depends on what is in the `ViewPager`.

Comment: Also check whether this touch event is overrided by other views touch events. For example, if you button over a textview, the touch on textview will not work..